# How to prove that $n\mid {a_1}^2+\cdots +{a}^2_{\phi (n)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n\in \Bbb N $ such that $\gcd(n,6)=1$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_{\phi( n)}$ are relatively prime with $n$ and smaller than $n$, how to prove : $$n\mid {a_1}^2+\cdots +{a}^2_{\phi (n)}$$

Comment: What is $a$ supposed to be?

Comment: $a$ is natural number that $(a_i,n)=1$ and $a_i \lt n$

Comment: This is false for general $a$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas thank you for notation.

Comment: @agustin: Maybe you mean $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}$ are all positive integers less than and relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: @P.. that's my interpretation too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the correct statement is the following.

Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(n, 6) = 1$. Show that in $\Bbb{Z} / n \Bbb{Z}$ we have
$$
\sum_{a \in \Bbb{Z} / n \Bbb{Z}^{*}} a^{2} = 0.
$$
It suffices to prove that the sum is zero modulo each $p^{e}$ in the prime decomposition $n = \prod p_i^{e_i}$.
$$
\sum_{a \in \Bbb{Z} / n \Bbb{Z}^{*}} a^{2}
=
\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{\varphi(p^e)} \sum_{a \in \Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}} a^{2}
=
2 \dfrac{\varphi(n)}{\varphi(p^e)} \sum_{b \in Q} b,
$$
where $Q$ is the set of  squares in $\Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}$, which has cardinality $(p^{e} -1)/2$, as $n$ is odd.

If $c$ is a fixed non-square in $\Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}$, then 
$$
\sum_{a \in \Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}} a
=
\sum_{b \in Q} b + \sum_{b \in Q} c b = (1+c) \sum_{b \in Q} b.\tag{1}
$$
Now the sum in (1) is zero in $\Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}$, because it does not change when multiplied by $1 \ne a \in \Bbb{Z} / p^e \Bbb{Z}^{*}$. And since $n$ is not $3$, there is a non-square $c \ne -1$, so $Q = 0$ modulo $p^{e}$.

Comment: This is an exercise in Tom Apostol's [book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analytic-Number-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387901639), page $48$ exercise $16$. The formula is $$\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}a_i^2=n\cdot\left(\frac{n}{3}\phi(n)+\frac16\prod_{p\mid n}(1-p)\right).$$

Comment: @P.. thanks, that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

$\gcd(n,6)=1 $ so $\gcd(n,2)=1,\gcd(n,3)=1$, also $\gcd(a_i,n)=1$ so $\gcd(2a_i,n)=1$

$$\{a_1,...,a_{\phi (n)}\}=\{2a_1,...,2a_{\phi (n)}\} $$

$a_1^2+...+a_{\phi (n)}^2\equiv 4a_1^2+...+4a_{\phi (n)}^2 \pmod n $ finally:

$n|3(a_1^2+...+a_{\phi (n)}^2)$ ,$\gcd(n,3)=1$ so $$n|a_1^2+...+a_{\phi (n)}^2$$